# Feedback Slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a Feedback-Slideshow for a eShop.

JS:

```
<script>
{literal}
$('#layout_feedback .feedback_button').on('click', function(){
    if($('#layout_feedback .firststep .content').css('display', 'none') == true){
        $('#layout_feedback .firststep .content').slideDown();
    }else{
        $('#layout_feedback .firststep .content').slideUp();
    }
});
$('#layout_feedback .firststep button').on('click', function(){
        $('#layout_feedback .firststep').slideUp();
        $('#layout_feedback .secondstep').slideDown();

        setTimeout(function(){
        $('#layout_feedback .firststep .content').slideUp();
        $('#layout_feedback .secondstep .content').slideUp();
        $('#layout_feedback .firststep').css('display','block');
        $('#layout_feedback .secondstep').css('display','none');
        $('#layout_feedback textarea').val('');
        }, 5000);
});
{/literal}
```

HTML:

There ist one (or more) Error(s) in JS, which can not find.
can anybody help me??

Tnx

Comment: The error should be displayed with a line number.

Comment: What error are you getting? Or is it just not working (and in this case what exactly should be happening vs what is happening)? Please provide some more information so people can actually help you :)